# How do I find a service whose name was changed; no alias

Tags: linux, services, search, delete

Here is the scenario: I do not have any prior services or programs, tripwire, etc., on my computer to tell me files or services that have changed. The integrity of a service, say `ps`, was changed so that it would actually execute the `netcat` command. I’ll explain it in another way. Say `netcat` was on my system but it was changed so that when you input `ps`, it would execute `netcat`.  It completely removed the actual `ps`service and replaced it with `netcat`, but it is still called/executed with `ps`. Now the question is this: How would I find out that netcat is now called by `ps`?

Comment: Did you check if it is an alias case? Type alias on your terminal and check the output

Comment: @BANJOSA well this is a scenario, this is more of a “if it happened” type of thing. And in it, they did not use an alias.

Comment: But are you having this issue or not?

Comment: Not at the moment.

Comment: You know that the goal here is to help people with real problems that could be debugged. In your case you can't supply any debugging information since it's not a real problem. You are just wasting time of people that could be trying to help other with real problems.

Comment: @BANJOSA I encounter situations like this during competitions and I just thought I’d at least ask a question about it. During my latest competition I actually encountered this situation. If you don’t feel that this question is a “real problem” and is not worth your time, then that is fine. All I was doing was asking a question, not thinking whether or not it mattered if the situation was an if it happened or a now problem.

Comment: @BANJOSA though I would have thought the fact that I said “Here is the scenario” wouldn’t have at least given you the idea that this question may not be an immediate problem, but rather an if it happened problem.

Comment: @BANJOSA This question has potential security implications. The fact that it is theoretical does not make it a "waste of time". You are always welcome to ignore this kind of question; it's not a zero-sum game.

Comment: Surely you can tell the difference by observing the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the tool

```
command -v ps
```

or

```
type ps
```

they will tell you the absolute path and if it is a builtin shell function or alias.